# how to add related field 'subject' along with model 'book' to be stored in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i am a newbie to rails 
i am stuck at a point
i have related models Book and Subject
where
Book related_to:Subject
and
Subject has_many:books

now what can i do to store subject field while saving the book instance

book model file :book.rb

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :price,:description , :created_at ,:subject
  belongs_to :subject
  validates_presence_of :title
  validates_numericality_of :price, :message=>"Error Message"
end
```

subject model file :subject.rb

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :books

end
```

my migration files are
book migration

```
class Books < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :books do |t|
      t.column :title, :string, :limit => 32, :null => false
      t.column :price, :float
      t.column :subject_id, :integer
      t.column :description, :text
      t.column :created_at, :string
    end
      Book.create :title =>"book1",:price =>500 , :description=>"book 1 created" , :created_at=>"12/12/12"
      Book.create :title =>"book2",:price =>111 , :description=>"book 2 created" , :created_at=>"12/12/12"
      Book.create :title =>"book3",:price =>222 , :description=>"book 3 created" , :created_at=>"12/12/12"
      Book.create :title =>"book4",:price =>333 , :description=>"book 4 created" , :created_at=>"12/12/12"
      Book.create :title =>"book5",:price =>444 , :description=>"book 5 created" , :created_at=>"12/12/12"
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :books
  end
end
```

subjects migration

```
class Subjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :subjects do |t|
      t.column :name, :string
    end
    Subject.create :name => "Physics"
    Subject.create :name => "Mathematics"
    Subject.create :name => "Chemistry"
    Subject.create :name => "Psychology"
    Subject.create :name => "Geography"
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :subjects
  end
end
```

my newBook html.erb

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> new Book </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><%= @hello_message %></h1>
        <h1>Add new book</h1>
        <%= form_tag :action => 'create' %>
        <p>
            <label for="book_title">Title</label>:
            <%= text_field 'book', 'title' %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="book_price">Price</label>:
            <%= text_field 'book', 'price' %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="book_subject">Subject</label>:
            <%= collection_select(:book,:subject_id,@subjects,:id,:name) %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="book_description">Description</label>
            <br/>
            <%= text_area 'book', 'description' %>
        </p>
        <%= submit_tag "Create" %>
        <%= form_tag %>
        <%= link_to 'Back', {:action => 'list'} %>
    </body>
</html>
```

when i try to save by my create action it says
**Can't mass-assign protected attributes: subject_id**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Book model, you should have:

```
 attr_accessible :title, :price, :description, :created_at, :subject_id
```

Comment: perfect , i did this , but made some other mistakes , but after your answer got it

Comment: BTW, you why do you set created_at value by hand?

Comment: I dont know how to get it created automatically

Answer (score 1):

Add accepts_nested_attributes_for :books in your `subject` model

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name
      has_many :books
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :books, :allow_destroy => true

    end
```

Comment: could you please explain the last line , whats the significance od adding it

Comment: Whenever you delete or create data in subject table it will also affect in book table and vise versa.